# (Twig) How to check if value taken from translation key (as string or array?) exists within product variant title

Tags: twig

(Twig) How can I check to see if a product variant title (which is used multi-lingual) in Twig exists within a translation key (which is a string, but I could change this to an array)?

For a webshop theme, I want to replace the "product.variant" variable (which is a platform variable and contains a variant title) with a CSS color swatch. The ecommerce platform doesnt provide a default way to do this, so I have to build a workaround which should work multi-lingual. Webshop-owners can enter their own label (name) for the color variant, so if webshop-owners use the string "Color", or "color", or "Farbe" (german) or whatever label name in whatever language, my workaround should be able to detect that "color label name" and replace this label value with a color swatch (via CSS, for this I need to know the label value, which is a color name like "blue", and in my CSS I guess I'll have to sum up all color names in as many languages as possible to make it work, I'm afraid, but this is ok). In my thinking I need to use a custom translation key so webshop-owners can enter the color name labels they want to work with, and compare these values with the "product variant" variables which are derived from the ecommerce platform. Can't figure out the right way to do so, anybody who can help me out? Much obliged!

This I tried:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
{% if theme.cstm_translkey_colorswatch_labelname | split(';') in variant.title %}
    <p style="background-color: green;color: yellow">Hi, show me a color swatch please!</p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This code below works, but it uses just 1 variant label name ('Color:'), and I need it multi-lingual):

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% if 'Color:' in variant.title or 'color:' in variant.title %}
    {% set colorSwatches = true %}
    {% set colorName = variant.title | trim('"Color: ') %}
    {% if colorName not in colorNamesArray %}
        {% set colorNamesArray = colorNamesArray | merge([colorName]) %}
    {% endif %}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

My goal is to have an array of color names that works in all languages that the webshop runs (and where each color name exists just once) that I can replace with a CSS color swatch (this last part is not so much the problem).

(added:)
Variant.title is the system variable for product variants to work with, it's a string that can look like a simple "Size: L", but can also consist of 2 or more attributes, like "Size: L, Color: Blue, Occasion: Casual" (like a matrix of variants). From this value I need to derive whether there's a "color" attribute (but: in all languages the shop offers), and if so, replace this color attribute with  a CSS color swatch in the color of the color attribute value (the part after "Color: "), while the order for the attributes can differ (first "Color", or maybe last or in the middle?). That is because web merchants can enter their own variant names/labels, in any order they want, that's what makes it complicated  (for me ;).

The other variable "theme.cstm_translkey_colorswatch_labelname"  is my own effort to try to work with a custom translation key for webmerchants to define which keys they want to use (and also in what languages) to use as label name for the color variants, so I can use this to compare that to the product "variant.title". They can enter the value (string) for this translation key in the backoffice. But not sure if this is the way to go...

Comment: Whats the content of `variant.title` and `theme.cstm_translkey_colorswatch_labelname`?

Answer (score 0):

The split will transform the string into an array. This means you can't use `in`straight away. You would need to loop all "languages":

```
{% for color in label|split(';') %}
    {% for title in titles %}
        {% if color|lower in title|lower %}
            {{ title }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/b1sw5b)

---

Do note this would be easier if you would split up the attributes in `title` in seperate fields or use somthing like [trans](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html) to translate `color` on the fly.

Comment: Thanx, I'll try it out!

Comment: stackoverflow.com/q/56338792/8631622 Please look into this problem. I did everything I could. But I could not solve this problem @DarkBee